# Transparent window with a completely transparent notch

Tags: html, css

I want to make a transparent window with a notch that is completely transparent. But probably I'm doing it incorrectly. Can anyone assist me with this?

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

.clear {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.line {
  background: White;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3vh;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3vh;
  height: 3vh;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <div class="clear">
          <div class="line"></div><br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The result I have:

[image]

Basically, I want to make that notch completely transparent to the background. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Have you tried `opacity: 0;`?

Comment: Yes, it does not work just removes it completely or makes it transparent to the window but not the main background.

Comment: You can try using an SVG mask: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-comprehensive-guide-to-clipping-and-masking-in-svg--cms-30380

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

.clear {
  background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/bC1LOp/White-Shape.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
        <div class="clear">
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here, I've made an image of what I believe you want and I have changed the background colour of `.clear` to the image.

Comment: Yeah it kinda works i think i can manage that. i also want to add a border around that but the image doesn't fill the edges of the border and also i want to force the border to follow down the notch and wont go above it. is it possible ? https://i.imgur.com/u80lw57.png https://i.imgur.com/pXbgEFp.png

Comment: @Marko I'll do it for you because the border needs to be added manually.

Comment: @Marko I tried my best! Try [this image](https://image.ibb.co/efFfOp/White-Shape-With-Border.png) instead. You'll just need to set the other sides (`border-top`, `border-left` and `border-right`) in your css.

Comment: This is all looks kinda shady it kinda works but it's probably better solution out there ?

Comment: @Marko I'll add another answer for you.

Comment: @Marko See my other answer I have added.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw the shape using SVG and then set its properties. Here's what you might want:

```js
// Declare container width
var vw = $("#svg").width();

// Declare container height
var vh = $("#svg").height();

$("#svg").html("<g id='polygon'><polygon points='0,0 " + ((vw / 100) * 25) + ",0 " + ((vw / 100) * 30) + ",10 " + ((vw / 100) * 70) + ",10 " + ((vw / 100) * 75) + ",0 " + vw + ",0 " + vw + "," + vh + " 0," + vh + "' /></g> Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG");
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: none;
}

#polygon {
  fill: white;
  fill-opacity: 0.7;
  stroke: red;
}

#svg {
  width: 98%;
  height: 90vh;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg">
    
</svg>
```